# ciper dofinal method with algo RSA/ECB/OAEPPadding throwing below exception

Tags: android

ciper dofinal method with algo RSA/ECB/OAEPPadding throwing below exception

final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(RSA/ECB/OAEPPadding);
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, new OAEPParameterSpec("SHA-256", "MGF1", MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA256, PSource.PSpecified.DEFAULT));

```
        cipherText = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

at this code cipherText = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)); i m getting below exception

Error:javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: error:0400007e:RSA routines:OPENSSL_internal:KEY_SIZE_TOO_SMALL
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: error:0400007e:RSA routines:OPENSSL_internal:KEY_SIZE_TOO_SMALL

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use below code only it working fine
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPPadding");
// To use SHA-256 the main digest and SHA-1 as the MGF1 digest
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, new OAEPParameterSpec("SHA-256", "MGF1", MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA1, PSource.PSpecified.DEFAULT));